# pgfplots coordinate list

Tags: pgfplots

I have a straightforward chart, using `\addplot` with a list of coordinates. Is there a way to insert a break in the line drawn by the coordinate list, something like `(x1,y1)(break)(x2,y2)` to prevent the line being drawn between the points either side of the break?

Answer (score 5):

To insert a break in the line, insert a line break in the coordinate list. Alternatively you can add an "invalid" coordinate, i.e. which contains instead of a number either `NaN` or `inf`, together with the `axis` option `unbounded coords=jump`.

(It seems imgur isn't working, so I can't update the image, but both yield the same result.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
% (copied from the PGFPlots manual v1.16 page 119)
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates {
                (0,0) (10,50) (20,100) (30,200)

                (50,600) (60,800) (80,1000)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            unbounded coords=jump,
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {
                (0,0) (10,50) (20,100) (30,200) (NaN,0) (50,600) (60,800) (80,1000)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you, I can work with that. Seems a little inelegant though, given that the code is fairly free format, and you might expect blank lines not to have any significance. Is there a more explicit alternative method?

Comment: See my edited answer.